# How do I write an encoded jpeg as bytes to Tensorflow tfrecord and then read it?

Tags: tensorflow, jpeg, encode, tfrecord

I am trying to use tensorflows tfrecords format to store my datasets.

I managed to read in jpeg images and decode them to raw format and write them to a tfrecord file. I can then later read them using tf.decode_raw.

The problem is that this leads to huge file sizes because I am storing the images as raw. Now I have seen many tutorials and blogs saying I can store them in an encoded format and then when reading them just decode them. I can't find any example of this. I have been trying for a while but no matter what way I do it I'm getting formatting errors.

TLDR
Does anyone know how to write images to a tfrecord file as jpegs and not as raw.

Thank You,
David.

My writing function.

```
def convert(image_paths, labels, out_path):

num_images = len(image_paths)

with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_path) as writer:
    for i, (path, label) in enumerate(zip(image_paths, labels)):

        print_progress(count=i, total=num_images-1)
        img = open(path, 'rb').read()

        data ={'image': wrap_bytes(img),
            'label': wrap_int64(label)}

        feature = tf.train.Features(feature=data)
        example = tf.train.Example(features=feature)
        serialized = example.SerializeToString()
        writer.write(serialized)
```

Convert dataset with this:

```
{convert(image_paths=image_paths_train,
    labels=cls_train,
    out_path=path_tfrecords_train)}
```

My Reading Function

```
def parse(serialized):

features = \
    {
        'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }
parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized,
                                         features=features)

# Get the image as raw bytes.
image_raw = parsed_example['image']

# Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
image = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw,channels=3)

#image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)

# The type is now uint8 but we need it to be float.
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)

# Get the label associated with the image.
label = parsed_example['label']

# The image and label are now correct TensorFlow types.
return image, label
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For writing, just open the file as a binary file (`fp = open('something.jpg', 'rb')`) and `.read()` its content. Store that content in the tfrecord `Example` as you store the image now (i.e., as a bytes feature).

For reading, instead of doing `decode_raw`, use `tf.image.decode_image` and pass in the tensor you get from the sample reader.

If you post your code, I can provide better code examples, but not knowing how your code looks like this is as detailed as I can get.

Comment: Hi GPhilo, Thanks, I've added my code. How could I go about displaying the image after using decode_image(). I seem to be getting an error when using plt.imshow(). Thanks your answer seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: When you work with TensorFlow's operations, (almost) all the operations so not return the data directly, but instead return `Tensor` objects that **will** contain your data _once the graph is actually run_. The distinction between graph creation time and graph execution time is a characteristic of TensorFlow and you might want to research more in that direction.

All that to say, you won't be able to print the result of decode_image directly in pyplot, you need to create a `sess = tf.Session()` and `sess.run(decoded_image)`

Comment: Also, your code looks OK to me, assuming `wrap_bytes` and `wrap_int64` are correct (which I have no reason to doubt).

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thinking in tensorflow takes some getting used to. I will try your above suggestion and display some images while running the a session. Thanks for your time GPhilo.